# Using parse_mode = HTML

Tags: google-apps-script, telegram-bot

So I needed something to act as a notifier and to connect it to my scripts, so I decided to try Telegram. I have successfully set up a Telegram bot. But I am having trouble in sending HTML formatted messages through the bot.

```
    function wire(message) {
    var token ='xxxxxxx';
    var channel_id = 'xxxx'
  var uid = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'+token+'/sendMessage?chat_id='+channel_id+'&text='+message+'&parse_mode=HTML';
  Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(uid));
 }

function test() {
    var body = "You were sent a message from <a href = http://www.example.com/profiles.php?XID=xxxxx>Batman</a> with the message:Hi";
    var bish = encodeURIComponent(body);
    wire(bish);

}
```

Running the function **test** gives me an error as:

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can't parse entities: Unexpected end of name token at byte offset 40"}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The href attribute needs to be in quotes. See [docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style).

Try:

```
var body = 'You were sent a message from <a href = "http://www.example.com/profiles.php?XID=xxxxx">Batman</a> with the message:Hi';
```